# Asp.Net Application Loads slowly in the initial load

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, iis-7

I have an ASP.NET application which is taking more time to load initially. After loading the first time, the page loads faster.

My page has an Image gallery. This gallery is loaded based on the category selection. This is done by ajax. When I click a particular category , it will load a gallery via ajax. But the problem is The first Ajax request to load a category will take more time. Second time we try to access the same category it will load faster.

I have not enabled the server-side and client-side caching. What actually happens behind scene? I think When I try to read a file from a disk for the first time, it will cache in memory and second time it will given from the memory. Is it true my assumption? So my questions are:

1.Will Os will disk cache the file read operation?

2.If not so what is the problem happening when open the first time?

3.How can resolve this problem? Is there any IIS setting or Page Level?

Please Help.

Comment: is it the first request for each category or is it only the first request to the application in general ?

Answer (score 0):

Try deploying a precompiled solution to the server:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228015(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: ASP Web Site != ASP Web Application

Comment: Publishing is a website is a Precompiled deployment Is it correct or not? Do We need to Precompile a wesite project if we choose publish and Deployment

Comment: It is not required to precompile an asp.net web site. 
For a MVC3 web application you can precompile the views http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7166820/precompile-a-asp-net4-mvc3-website-using-visual-studio-2010