# How to precompile ASP.Net MVC4 website in VS 2010 during Publishing?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2010, publish, precompile, aspnet-compiler

How do I precompile an ASP.Net MVC4 website in Visual Studio 2010 at the time of Publishing?

I didn't find any option in Visual Studio project / solution settings. I checked the Package/Publish Setting by right clicking on the project but didn't find any relevant settings.

I know there exists command line option (aspnet_compile.exe) but I wish to achieve this using Visual Studio 2010.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Precompile a asp.net4 mvc3 website using visual studio 2010](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7166820/precompile-a-asp-net4-mvc3-website-using-visual-studio-2010)

Answer (score 0):

well.project is already compiled when you publish it(except views).if you want to compile views,then edit your projet file and add

```
<MvcBuildViews>true</MvcBuildViews>
```

ps: you have to unload project before you can edit project file

Comment: Also be sure that <EnableUpdatable>false</EnableUpdatable> is false otherwise views wont be pre-compiled.